# What is the projected coordinate system equivalent for ETRS89?

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg, cartesian

ETRS89 (EPSG: 4258) is the EU-recommended frame of reference for geodata for Europe [1](https://confluence.qps.nl/qinsy/latest/en/european-terrestrial-reference-system-89-etrs89-182618396.html). This coordinate system is geographic. However, in the software world, we need to transform it into a projected coordinate system in order to take measurements.

Is the ETRS89-extended / LAEA Europe (EPSG: 3035) the right equivalent?

Comment: "ETRS89 (EPSG:4258) is the most commonly used reference system in the EU" - citation needed. You are aware that there'll be significant distortions across Europe if you use a projected CRS?

Comment: You cannot generalise it this way. E.g. in germany ETRS89 / UTM zone xx is used as official projected CRS by governmental authorities.

Comment: I added the reference. I am aware that it will not be a 1:1 correspondence, however could you please elaborate what you mean by "significant"?

Comment: @MrXsquared That's what I was afraid of.