# Creating circle around point with specific radius taken from column in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, polygon-creation, circle, radius

I have a shapefile of points (SR EPSG:3857 - WGS 84), with (in the attributes) an `"ID"` column for each point, and a `"radius"` length in meters; I am trying to find a way to create a buffer (or a circular polygon) around each point.

The radius of the buffer should be taken from its column, and it is different for each point. How can I do that? And is there a way to automate the creation of this buffer?

I am using QGIS Desktop 3.4.8 with GRASS 7.6.1.

Comment: Are you aware if the fact that `EPSG:3857` does not return rwal world distances? Length is heavily distorted - so depending on what you want to do, these buffers might lwad to completely wrong results

Comment: @Babel no, I didn't know. Do you suggest using EPSG:4326 instead?

Comment: No, `EPSG:4326` has degrees as length units, thus this makes no sense. Which CRS depends on your area of interest. Use local UTM zone or - for the whole world - an equal area projection.

Comment: Thanks Babel. I found information on the Equal Earth Projection, I will try to implement it (the area of study is the whole Europe) and try again.

Comment: Check also these threads: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/212031/99589 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/390815/99589

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using `Vector geometry > Buffer` tool in Processing Toolbox, you can specify the field that contains the radius value, as in the image:

[image]

After selecting a field, `Distance` parameter will be inactive.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this actually works. But I also calculated the area the circle should have (with r*r*3.14) and it is very different from what I obtain if, after constructing the circle in the way you suggested, I calculate the area (through Field calculator > New field > Geometry > $area). Do you know why?

Comment: That has to do with the CRS you use - see my other comment.

Comment: @LisaTedeschi, please check this answer : https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/375628/99589

Answer (score 7):

#### [image] This algorithm is deprecated and can be removed anytime. Prefer using Buffer algorithm instead.

---

There is ["Variable distance buffer"](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/modelertools.html#variable-distance-buffer) geoalgorithm for that.

> **Keep in mind :** This tool is only available in the Graphical Modeler. It is not available in the Processing Toolbox.

[image: example]

Comment: Thanks, this is also useful. But I have the same problem as for the method suggested by Kadir Şahbaz, that is the calculation of the area: I also calculated the area the circle should have (with r*r*3.14) and it is very different from what I obtain if, after constructing the circle, I calculate the area. And the Attribute table of the Buffer shapefile I obtain with your method has only one ID column with only one row, despite the starting shapefile having many different columns and rows, and therefore it is impossible to calculate the different areas of the different circle polygons I have.

Answer (score 1):

There is also SAGA's ["Feature Buffer"](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.2.6/shapes_tools_18.html) geoalgorithm available in the QGIS's Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

[image: example]